# Relationship between extension generic parameters and Func argument generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, extension-methods

So I guess I don't really understand the above. Like suppose you have an extension on an enumerable type like so....

```
public static TElement StringMatch<TElement, TData>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> source,
        Func<TElement, TData> selector)
```

All is fine here, but I've been assuming that the StringMatch generic parameters mirror the Func generic parameters, since the `Func<>` is what appears to the user to be passed.

But say I want to specify that the return type of `Func<>` is a specific parameter, maybe like `Func<TElement, string>`

Now my thought would be to alter the signature like so...

```
public static TElement StringMatch<TElement, string>(
            this IEnumerable<TElement> source,
            Func<TElement, string> selector)
```

...again, to mirror the passed Func<>. But if I try to invoke this on something like `Books.StringMatch(b => b.Title)`, I get an error like...

```
'Book' does not contain a definition for 'StringMatch' and no extension method 'StringMatch' accepting a first argument of type 'Book' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So what's the deal here? What **exactly** do the generic parameters in an extension method specify?

Comment: Your second signature won't compile since you're asking the compiler to find a type called "TData". As you're not including it in the generic method definition, the compiler doesn't know TData is supposed to be a generic type parameter. Maybe I'm really missing something, but could you maybe elaborate as to what you want StringMatch to do?

Comment: Oops, that's actually a mistake, editing now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have

```
public static TElement StringMatch<TElement, TData>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> source,
    Func<TElement, TData> selector)
```

it covers the case where the caller passes a `Func` where `TData` is `string`.

If you want `TData` to always be the specific type `string` then simply remove that as a formal generic parameter in the method:

```
public static TElement StringMatch<TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> source,
    Func<TElement, string> selector)
```

You can, of course, implement both. The compiler will select the most specific one. The caller can also specify the type parameters explicitly to leave only one choice.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense. So the generic parameters of the extension method just include all the generic parameters included in arguments to that method, not including the enumeration you're extending? I think what was confusing me was that generic arguments and Func parameters use the same syntax, I was thinking there *had* to be 2 generic parameters because of the 2 Func parameters

Comment: The ones after the method or delegate name are formal parameter declarations. (They can also be after a class/interface name in a class/interface declaration.) Anywhere else are references to those. They can be used in the return type, parameter types, or anywhere in the body where a type is used. (They can even be unused.)